# How to add an item to an order without a hidden field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app when a user clicks on "Order" link next to a product, Rails take him to a form where he can specify the amount he wants, etc.

```
new_order_path(product: product)
```

The page has a hidden field which takes a parameter to know which product we are adding to this new order

```
<%= f.hidden_field :product_id, :value => @product.id %>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to submit the product_id to my order without using a hidden field.

my current controller

```
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @product = Product.find_by(params[:id])
  end

def create
    @product = Product.find_by(params[:id])
    @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
    if @order.save
      flash[:success] = 'Order created'
      redirect_to root_url
    else  
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the product id in the session hash:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @product = Product.find_by(params[:id])
  session[:product_id] = @product.id
end

def create
  @product = Product.find_by(session[:product_id])
  ...
end
```